# Extract particular part of string in C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

> N\r\n XXXX XXXX -XXXX XXXXX 45 108 10 N\r\nJ\r\nT\r\n***(10) 5 2738372 
>   827172672 2*** X 345 145/00\r\nXxxxxx:\r\nXxxxxx \r\nXxxxxx \r\nXXXXX 21 
>   \r\nXXXXXX 2´t Xxx

I have this string from PDF
I just want those extract specific part and display it

Thanks in advance

Comment: And have you tried *anything*? SO really isn't a code writing service. Is it always on the 5th line? Is it always the same length, and always start at the beginning of the line? Is it always the same text? You haven't given us nearly enough information about the problem.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, `String.Split`, `String.Substring`, `Regular Expression` can potentially solve your issue.

Comment: Is is always same length and always at start of 4th new line. Need to extract this part (10) 5 2738372 827172672 2 in above text.

Comment: I am trying with String.Split and String.Substring ... will Regex.Match be more helpful in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely an alternative to Jim's provided solution. You can use [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to achieve the same result. (This is of course if the expected number of digits is constant. Otherwise, you would need to adjust the pattern slightly to accommodate)

Where the source string is:

> N\r\n XXXX XXXX -XXXX XXXXX 45 108 10 N\r\nJ\r\nT\r\n***(10) 5 2738372
>   827172672 2*** X 345 145/00\r\nXxxxxx:\r\nXxxxxx \r\nXxxxxx \r\nXXXXX
>   21 \r\nXXXXXX 2´t Xxx

Using the pattern:

> \(\d{2}\)\s\d\s\d{7}\s\d{9}\s\d

Which can be explained in the following way:

```
\(\d{2}\)  -  Where the string starts with ( and contains 2 numeric digits followed by )
\s\d\      -  and is followed by a space and a numeric digit
\s\d{7}    -  and is then followed by a space and 7 numeric digits
\s\d{9}    -  and is then followed by a space and 9 numeric digits
\s\d       -  and finally ending with a space and a single numeric digit
```

You can use:

```
public static string ParseValue(string sourceStr)
{
    string pattern = @"\(\d{2}\)\s\d\s\d{7}\s\d{9}\s\d";
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(sourceStr, pattern).Value;
}
```

Which would give you the following result:

```
(10) 5 2738372 827172672 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same length on the 4th line, then this should do it:

```
const int TextLength = 26; // length of text you want
// text is the string that contains the data.

// get the 4th line
string line = text.Split(new[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[3];

// and extract the text you want
string foo = line.SubString(TextLength);
```